# How to disable cache in joomla template?

Tags: joomla

I have disabled cache in Global Configuration to System = OFF.
Global Configuration to server to Gzip Page Compression to NO.
Plug-in Manager to System-Cache = Disable.
I can see in the view source page there are files coming from cache folder for template, also when I go to Maintenance to clear cache (admin panel) and clear it manually and again load the page it again shows up template and widgetkit files in clear cache window.

Can somebody tell me where I am going wrong? I am using Yoo Steam theme.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you select the correct answer please?

Comment: Done. Sorry I am a newbie :)

Comment: Ho about if i don't have access to the administrator account, but have access to the database.
Then how can we enable it from database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the Theme settings there might be a caching plugin they use. Disable all the concatenation, minification, gzipping also.

Go to `Extensions -> Templates manager` and check these settings on your template.